# How to get data-target value using data-room in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get data-target value using data-room in jquery.
Example:

```
<div data-target="10" data-room="test@gmail.com"></div>
```

Note: test@gmail.com is a dynamic value.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Construct an attribute selector, with the email address inserted as the search term.

```
var target = $('[data-room="' + email + '"]').data('target');
```

An attribute selector normally looks like this, but you are adding the search text dynamically:

```
$('[data-room="searchtext"]');
```

Note: the double quotes are important as the search text contains special characters. Otherwise they might be treated as part of the selector and cause it to break.

Comment: Thank you Mr. TrueBlueAussie

Comment: @Durairaj: No problem. Mark as *answer* when you can. Thanks.